# HeapSort vs QuickSort performance

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort

I have two implementations of sort, one being HeapSort and second one QuickSort. From what I heard, QuickSort should have better average case performance, but from my tests, it performs 4 times worse than HeapSort for array of random integers. If those integers are in interval smaller than is size of array, the performance is even slower (20 times worse).

1. Do you see any major flaws in my QuickSort algorithm?
2. Is there any good method for choosing pivot that works for any type T? I tried choosing middle element of array, but time performance went ever worse.

   ```
   template <typename T>
   void
   IndexedSequence<T>::Sort(QuickSortTag,
                            Comparator<T> comparator,
                            signed long from, signed long to)
   {
   AdjustSubSequence(from,to);
   if(to-from < 2) {
       return;
   }
   if(to-from == 2) {
       if(comparator(operator[](from),operator[](to-1)) == GREATER_THAN) {
           Swap(operator[](from),operator[](to-1));
       }
       return;
   }
   Type pivot = operator[](to-1);
   signed long left = from, right = to-2;
   while(true) {
       while(comparator(operator[](left),pivot) == SMALLER_THAN) {
           ++left;
       }
       while((comparator(operator[](right),pivot) != SMALLER_THAN) && right > 0) {
           --right;
       }
       if(left >= right--) {
           Swap(operator[](to-1),operator[](left));
           break;
       } else {
           Swap(operator[](left),operator[](right));
       }
   }
   Sort(QuickSortTag(),comparator,from,left);
   Sort(QuickSortTag(),comparator,left+1,to);
   }
   ```

   Here is my test code:

   ```
   Buffer<signed long> buf1;

   Buffer<signed long> buf2;

   srand(14225);
   for(signed long i = 0; i < 100000l; ++i) {
       buf1.AddBack(rand()%500000000l);
   }
   buf2 = buf1;

   clock_t t1, t2;        
   t1 = clock();
   buf1.Sort(HeapSortTag(),AscendingCompare);
   t2 = clock();
   std::cout << "Time of heap sort: " << (double)(t2-t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
   t1 = clock();
   buf2.Sort(QuickSortTag(),AscendingCompare);
   t2 = clock();
   std::cout << "Time of quick sort: " << (double)(t2-t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
   ```

Output:

```
Time of heap sort: 0.047
Time of quick sort: 0.243
```

Comment: Firstly, what you've read about their relative efficiency is big-O analysis, and there are constant factors which may make heap sort quicker until some threshold number of elements is reached.  Second, it's a good idea to do a few sanity checks around these things: check the sorted buf1 == buf2, put a `for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)` around the benchmarks so they're running a couple times and there's no potential first-sorter cache warming advantage (as is, `buf2 = buf1` may leave quite a bit of `buf1` in cache - by the time `buf2` gets sorted there may be none of it in cache.

Comment: There's also the fact that you shouldn't recurse down to the one-or-two-element case. Once the range is small enough, you should use something like insertion sort with a small constant factor.

Comment: This would have been a perfect candidate for codereview :)!